# Promoting SSRS Report through different environments - Datasource

Tags: deployment, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Within our infrastructure we have a UAT, PreProd (staging area), and Prod (Live) environment.  I'm locked down obviously to only being able to create reports in our UAT environment.  My question is, when creating a datasource within an SSRS report you obviously attach a server name to this, so i would add our UAT server.  When this is promoted to our PreProd environment, how can i ensure that this server name picks up our PreProd server and not has the UAT server name embedded into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Create Shared datasources , say, "SharedDataSource"
2. Have this shared datasource as a part of all the report  projects that you work on and or controlled by source code repository
3. Make sure that this "SharedDataSource" is deployed on all the 3 servers, UAT, PreProd, and Prod. And on each of these servers the datasource is pointing to the right server with appropriate credentials.
4. Now when you work on a report project , for each of the reports you work on create a Report Datasource, say RptDataSource, which uses the option "Use shared data source refernce" and points to the SharedDataSource. In this way you would have another layer of indirection which would offer flexibility.

You are done. Create reports ... deploy them on UAT server .. have them tested ... promote them to PreProd and repeat the process ... and finally to the Prod.

Comment: thanks for the response.  this makes complete sense to me having looked into this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using embed datasource, use shared datasource. Refre this link for more details
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155845(v=sql.100).aspx)